# Creating XMLHttpRequest object with Object.create()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Coming from a class-based OOP background (C++/Java/C#), I'm on the path of learning object-oriented JavaScript. I often read advice about using `Object.create(...)` instead of `new ...` when dealing with objects is JS.

So I tried to create AJAX calls that way :

```
var req = Object.create(XMLHttpRequest);
req.open(...); // TypeError: req.open is not a function
```

Shouldn't `open` be in `req`'s prototype chain ?

I also tried to apply the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor function to my object :

```
var req = Object.create(XMLHttpRequest);
XMLHttpRequest.apply(req, null); // Constructor XMLHttpRequest requires 'new'
```

Just when I thought I was out of trouble with JS's OO way, this pulls me back in :)

Many thanks to those who'll help me understand what's going on here.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is a function.

Comment: "*I often read advice about using Object.create(...) instead of new ...*" - no. Please read it again. They are not exchangeable.

Comment: ya, try print out these two will help you understand .  console.log(new XMLHttpRequest()); console.log(Object.create(XMLHttpRequest));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` is designed to return the request object when invoked as a constructor: `var req = new XMLHttpRequest()`. `Object.create(proto)` creates a new object with the prototype as the first parameter.
The 2 approaches do different things: object creation and initialisation (first case) and simply create a new object with prototype (second case).

---

Of course you could try to accomplish the same thing this way (not recommended):

```
var obj = Object.create(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
XMLHttpRequest.call(obj); // initialize the request
```

which is almost equivalent to:

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But you receive an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'XMLHttpRequest': Please use
>   the 'new' operator

---

So the correct solution is to use `new XMLHttpRequest()`.
Take a look at the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), which is near what you try to accomplish. But it has a limited support in browsers.